# How do i show in-group percenteges in facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to visualize students' tendency to drop out depending on their previous education. I have two variables of interest; "gymnasiegrov" which shows their high school programme and "totstatus_tri", which shows outcome and has three levels (quit first term, quit later, still in program).

So far, I have managed to make a decent visualization using the following code:

```
ggplot(fulldata, aes(x=fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))) + 
  geom_bar()+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(fct_infreq(fulldata$gymnasiegrov))))+
  facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

I then get the following result:

[image]

This is an okay visualization, but there are "a lot" more students from some programmes than others. This makes patterns hard to distinguish. I would much rather see in-group percentages for each programme, so that the percentages of each outcome would sum to 100% for every programme across facets.

For instance, the largest programme (Ekonomiprogrammet/Ekonomi) has a total of 55 students, so the uppermost bar in the first facet should read 34/55, the bar in the second 15/55, the bar in the third 6/55 and so forth.

Would this be possible?

EDIT:

Posting data from the two relevant variables (since we have 14 different subgroups a "small" sample of 20 or so observations may not be very meaningful):

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA, "specialutformat program", "estetiska programmet", "medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", "komvux", 
"estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "specialutformat program", 
"friskoleprogram", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"teknikprogrammet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"komvux", "specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "komvux", 
"Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "specialutformat program", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "komvux", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "estetiska programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), totstatus_tri = c("troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier"
)), row.names = c(NA, -162L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (where antal is your count variable)?

```
library(tidyverse)
fulldata %>% 
    group_by(gymnasiegrov) %>% 
    mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal)) %>% 
    ggplot(.) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

Edit:

```
fulldata %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
  summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
  mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))
```

Comment: I first create an "antal" variable which reads 1 for every observation. I then apply your code. I then get an error message saying that "Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic."?

Comment: @Magnus try geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) instead

Comment: I'll have to get back to you tomorrow, thanks for your input! :)

Comment: It does produce a plot now but the numers don't add up to 1.0 across facets. "Ekonomiprogrammet/ekonomi" should read 0.62, 0.27, 0.11 but it reads 0.22, 0.09, 0.04 (ish)

Comment: I think I see the problem, the code doesn't calculate the groupwise "andel", we're getting a global value.

Comment: I "think" I could get groupwise values using the summarize verbs, but that will only give me one value per group, I can create a new df and join that to the old one for same value of "gymnasiegrov", or is there a better way?

Comment: @Magnus please provide a small reproducible example of your data

Comment: I think I already solved this using the workaround I mentioned (your answer set me on the right path so I'll accept it no matter what) but I can dput an exceprt into the original post.